# error with if statement, missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I have tried this code:

```
My_fun <- function(first_argument, second_argument, w=c(0.5,0.4){


      for( i in 1:2){
      if(w[i] < 0){
        stop("w must be positive")
      }
    }
    }
```

And I got this error:

> ```
> Error in if (w[i] < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> ```

Where is my problem? any help please? I think my code should work well!!

Comment: Probably safer to use `for( i in w)` in these cases, since you are expecting a vector anyway. But, after adding a `)` before the `{` in the first line, you function worked fine for me using `My_fun(1, 2)` and `My_fun(1, 2, w=c(-1))`.

Comment: @Imo Thank you so  much. it is work now. Sorry, my code is very long and complex ( I just introduced a simple example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, its missing a ")" in 1ºline, after w=c(0.5,0.4)

how you call the function?
if you called like "My_fun(1,2)"  its work.

but like lmo say, Probably safer to use for( i in w) in these cases, since you are expecting a vector anyway